# A version of KKT theorem. Looking for a reference

Tags: optimization, vector-spaces, karush-kuhn-tucker

I have been told that the following optimization theorem holds and is true. 
I would like to verify this or find a reference. I have searched some standard books that I know (e.g. Luenberger).

> **Theorem.** Let $X$ be a vectors space. Let $f:S \to \mathbb{R}$ and $h:S \to \mathbb{R}$ be concave functions over
>   a convex subset $S \subset X$. Assume that there exists a point $x_0
>  \in S$ such that $h(x_0) <0$.  Let \begin{align} \text{Obj}=\sup_{x
>  \in S \text{ and } h(x)\le 0} f(x).  \,\,\,\,  eq.(1) \end{align} Then,
>   there exists a constant $\lambda \ge 0$ such that \begin{align}
>  \text{Obj}= \sup_{x \in S } \left( f(x)-\lambda h(x) \right).  
>  \,\,\,\,  eq.(2) \end{align} Morover, if the supremum is attainable in
>   eq.(1)  by $x^* \in S$ that satisfies $h(x^*)\le 0$, then the supremum
>   is also attainted by $x^*$ in eq.(2).

**Another question:**  Does the fact $h(x)$ is concave make this theorem difficult to show? Here the constraint is $h(x) \le 0$ instead of $h(x) \ge 0$, is this problemtic?

Comment: Have you confounded $g(.)$ and $h(.)$?  You probably want to specify that all your functions are real valued.

Comment: @EricFisher Thanks. I added this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have a counterexample.

Take $S = X = \mathbb R$ and let $f(x) = -x^2$, $h(x) = 1 - x^4$. Then:

- Maximizing $-x^2$ over all $x$ where $1-x^4 \le 0$ means minimizing $x^2$ over $(-\infty,-1] \cup [1,\infty)$, so the optimal solution is $x^* = \pm1$ with $\text{Obj} = -1$.
- But $-x^2 - \lambda(1-x^4) = \lambda x^4 - x^2 - \lambda$ never has the right supremum. When $\lambda=0$, $-x^2$ is maximized at $0$, and the supremum is also $0$. When $\lambda>0$, the $x^4$ term dominates and we can make $\lambda x^4 - x^2 - \lambda$ arbitrarily large.

You're right that the concavity of $h$ is the problem. If $h$ were convex (or if $h$ were concave but the constraint were $h(x) \ge 0$, which corresponds to $g(x) \le 0$ for the convex function $g(x) = -h(x)$) then this would just be the Slater condition.

Essentially the reason the Slater condition works, but the statement with a concave $h$ does not, is that convex functions can't decrease too quickly. At any point $x_0$ in the domain of a convex function $g$, there exists a slope $d$ such that $g(x) \ge g(x_0) + d(x-x_0)$; we can take $d = g'(x_0)$ if $g'(x_0)$ exists. (There's a dot-product version of this for $\mathbb R^n$, and probably a linear-functional version of this for arbitrary vector spaces $X$.)

As a result, if the condition were $g(x) \le 0$, where $g$ is convex, then we can put a linear lower bound on $g$, so as we get "deeper" into the feasible region $\{x : g(x) \le 0\}$, the value of $-\lambda g(x)$ increases at worst at a constant rate that, by the choice of $\lambda$, we can make as small as we like until it's not worth it. (A constant rate is enough to achieve this because $f(x)$ is concave, so there is also a linear upper bound on $f$.)

But in the example above, the function $h(x)=1-x^4$ decreases very quickly as we go further into the feasible region $\{ x: 1-x^4 \le 0\}$. No matter what the value of $\lambda$ is, if $\lambda>0$, the term $-\lambda(1-x^4)$ rewards us much faster than the $-x^2$ term decreases, so for all $\lambda>0$, we want to go as far into the feasible region as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample.  I have one more question. For the above problem theorem to hold what would be an assumption that we have to make?

Comment: I don't think there's a natural additional assumption that works. As mentioned above, the theorem would be true if $h$ were convex. (So if we added "also, $h$ is convex" to the statement, it would hold - if we do this but don't drop "$h$ is concave" as a condition, it would mean $h$ is linear.)

Comment: @Misha Is there a formal reference for the case that $h$ is convex? That can directly answer a bountied question I've posted here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4068885/constrained-optimization-in-calculus-of-variations

Comment: @afshi7n It's the KKT theorem with Slater's condition.

Comment: @MishaLavrov The version of KKT that I have seen is for $X$ being a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I understand from the above discussion it should hold even for when $X$ is a function space, but is there a reference for that? Thank you

Comment: @afshi7n Oh, I see what you're looking for now. Well, it should be provable in the same way, assuming that the conditions required actually hold for your convex program, which I'm not convinced but will think about.